# The closure of a set of closed points

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, gn.general-topology

Let $X $ be a compact non-Hausdorff topological space with the following property: for every infinite subset of closed points, say $\{x_i\}_{i \in I}$, there exists $j\in I$ such that $x_j$ is in the closure of $\{x_i\}_{i \not=j}$.

Is there any characterization of such spaces? Or is there any sufficient or necessary condition for this property? Thanks for any help.

Comment: You should edit your question to be clearer.

Comment: I fixed up the grammar a little.  To clarify, a "closed point" is a point $x$ such that $\{x\}$ is closed?

Comment: Your edit reversed the changes I made; did you mean to do that?

Comment: This looks rather like a homework exercise. What's the motivation for asking the question...?